# Unable to update SDK components within Android Studio 2.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

So when I opened Android Studio today, there was a notification telling me that there is an update available for the Android Support Repository. I clicked on the update link and I received this warning:

> Due to your system configuration and the packages to be installed,  it
>   is likely that the following packages cannot be successfully installed
>   while Android Studio is running.
>
> Please exit and install the following packages using the standalone
>   SDK manager:
>
> ```
>    -Android Support Repository
> ```

I went in the Android SDK settings page and it gave me the same result when clicking Apply.

My SDK is in `C:\Android\sdk\` so it can't be a problem with rights elevation. I had the SDK installed **before** I installed Android Studio, however I had some problems with the SDK so I completely flushed and **reinstalled it**, while Android Studio was installed.

I also used the edit link next to the path (in the Android SDK settings) and I went through the setup, Android Studio found everything and had nothing to do. There was an update for the latest platform which I did through that instead and Android Studio installed it properly **without needing the standalone manager**.

Is it just that this component must be updated from the standalone manager or is it a problem with my Android Studio and/or the standalone manager?

***UPDATE:*** I have tried to update from the main menu (after closing the active project) and it still asks me to open the standalone.

To be clear: **I can update properly from the standalone SDK manager and there is no problem with opening it**, however I have seen a clean install on a colleague's computer and he could install additional components directly inside Android Studio without using the standalone manager at all, so I find it quite annoying to close, update and reopen when I shouldn't have to.

Should I risk to attempt the update from Android Studio (as there is a button for it), reinstall or repair Android Studio or do I need to flush absolutely everything and install from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure if this will help but - try uninstalling everything to do with android studio (the ide, sdk, etc.). Also delete every file they created on your computer.

Did you download the 1.2 GB android studio all in one? If not, make sure to grab that one.

Also, make sure your Java SDK is also installed and that your Windows environment variable points to the sdk location correctly.

Finally, you do have to exit android studio in order for the sdk standalone to work properly.

Hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: I kinda wanted to avoid uninstalling all the 10+ GB related to Android Studio and the SDK, if I need to to that then I'll just do as Android Studio says use the exit and launch standalone like I'm doing right now. No it was not the whole 1.2 GB, I already had the SDK installed. It's certainly not a problem with the JDK. I'm supposed to be able to update from Android Studio without closing and launching the standalone, I asked my colleagues and friends and they can update directly from Android Studio.

Comment: Sorry, not sure then. But I just went through the same exact error as you, but I exited as per instructed and the sdk standalone opened and I am able to update/install fine. Are you able to with the standalone and with android studio closed?

Comment: Yes I can update by closing Android Studio and using the standalone, this is not a problem, it is just really annoying to have to close and reopen after update when it is normally able to do so... When the next update will come, I will close the active project and try the update from the "main menue" and see if it is just because it can't update when a project is active.